# Customize the Link Dialog in dojo editor

Tags: customization, dojo

Release: Dojo 1.6.1

I am working on the dojo editor. The dojo editor has the Link dialog in which the target url can open in 4 ways - Current Window, New Window, Topmost Window, Parent Window.
Is there any way I can **disable the options** I dont need?
I tried removing the 3 by modifying the LinkDialog.js. It removed the ones I didnt need but still retained the space for them.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: Modified the LinkDialog.js to add disabled param in template